# Java ME Bluetooth linking error

Tags: java, java-me, bluetooth

I'm begining to Bluetooth java programming so I started by compiling the simple Bluettoth application that comes bundled into NetBeans, the application compiles correctly, but when I try to run any emulator for a cellphone I got this errors: (yes, I have reinstalled java, Netbeans 7.01, I don't know what else try, my rig is a Ci7 2630QM 4 GB Ram W7 64 bits)

```
Jad URL for OTA execution: http://localhost:8082/servlet/org.netbeans.modules.mobility.project.jam.JAMServlet/C%3A/Users/Raul/Documents/NetBeansProjects/BluetoothDemo2/dist/ClamshellCldcPhone1/BluetoothDemo2.jad
Starting emulator in execution mode
Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.
C:\Users\Raul\Documents\NetBeansProjects\BluetoothDemo2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:915: Execution failed with error code 2.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

please, I need desperately a solution :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you have JAVA_HOME environment variable set? Set the JAVA_HOME variable to point to a valid Java installation.